# Ears she has but she does not hear. Who is she?

Tags: riddle

Hands she has but does not hold,

teeth she has but does not bite,

feet she has but they are cold,

eyes she has but without sight.

Who is she?

solved: it was indeed from a geeky riddle site. I'll try to come up with some myself next time

Comment: This same riddle (and answer) can be found on a number of riddle websites.  Could you provide attribution to where you got it from?

Comment: @BoAlsemgeest, could you please edit the question to include more detailed attribution -- preferably including a link to the question on whatever site you found it on? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a

> Doll

It logically fits all of the requirements

Comment: Kind of a creepy riddle

Comment: heh. is it `Annabelle`

Comment: Shes coming for you